# Set default value in column IF condition is met in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, create-table, getdate

First of all, I'm very new with SQL query, so I apologize if I sound ignorant...

I have a database that has a stored job to drop and create a table every hour. The table looks like this, except there is data for every hour in between 1 and 24

```
Name         Hour1  Hour24
Point 1 OUT  4      5
Point 1 IN   26     22
Point 2 OUT  46     44    
Point 2 IN   0      0
Point 3 OUT  18     19
Point 3 IN   56     51
Point 4 OUT  111    100
Point 4 IN   0      0
Point 5 OUT  0      0
Point 5 IN   42     46
Point 6 IN   210    211
```

After the drop and create, the database adds a column at the end called date and sets todays date as the default.  My problem is when importing the data at 12:00am, the current date is actually tomorrow.  For accounting purposes, I need that data to have the same day.

I took a shot in the dark and tried this, but the syntax is all wrong...

```
[Date] [datetime] DEFAULT if(DATEPART(hh)=24) CONVERT(GETDATE(DATEPART(dd)-1))
```

Is an if statement like this possible in a create table query?  Is there a better way of going about this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried [`datediff`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)?

Comment: I'm sure i was using datediff incorrectly, but i tried declaring a variable to collect the current hour using convert(varchar(2),getdate(),108) and using it in a datediff like this:  select datediff(hh,24,@hour).  It retured -240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a default value, but you want the syntax to be correct:

```
[date] datetime default (case when datepart(hh, getdate()) = 24 then getdate() - 1 else getdate() end)
```

However, I don't think you should have a `datetime` value in a field called "date".  How about:

```
AsOfDate date default (case when datepart(hh, getdate()) = 24 then cast(getdate() - 1 as date) else cast(getdate() as date) end)
```

Comment: i believe that will do the trick!!  I'll know for sure after midnight tonight.  Thanks for the help, and the suggestion for the date field name!

Comment: @bonneyt . . . To be honest, I had never used the `case` statement for default values and was pleased to see that it works.  I might have use for this in the future.