# MySQL - Adding new column with default value when condition is met

Tags: mysql

I have an existing requests table in which I want to add a new column request_type. I want to set the default value of this column to A when a certain column is not null else B. I wrote the following query which shows syntax error for MySQL version 5.7.9 -

```
alter table requests
add column request_type enum('A','B','C') collate utf8_unicode_ci not null default (case when userid is not null then 'A' else 'B' end)
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support expressions for the `DEFAULT`.

But you can use MySQL 5.7's new feature for `GENERATED` columns: http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/

If you're using an older version of MySQL, you'd have to use a trigger to keep the enum column updated according to userid.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632703/set-default-value-in-column-if-condition-is-met-in-sql-2008) Isn't this similar?

Comment: That's a question about Microsoft SQL Server, which is a different product and has different features.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad.